# My first program in Android using Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am not able to connect to my app. Not getting what to enter in appPack and appActivity.

Steps Followed:

1. Started Appium Server and connected node appium
2. Executed the below script

My device is connected and showing online too. When I executed this code it is not showing any error.

Please let me know where my script is incorrect.

```
public class testApp {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public class movein {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebDriver dr;
    @Test
    public void testApp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{


        File app = new File("F:\\Mobile-testing\\apps\abc.apk");
         DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Nexus 5");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.4");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
         capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

           capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.abc");
           capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.abc");

           dr = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
           dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

           // clicking

            }


}

}
```

My Appium settings :

```
Server : 127.0.0.1 Port :4723
```

My Appium information :

```
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVers‌​ion":"18","automationName":"Appium"}
```

I have appPack and entered appActivity too from adb logs. Now I am facing the error:

> (org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.)

I  changed from `RemoteWebDriver` to `AppiumDriver<>`. It is executing and now showing error message:

> Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: spawn ENOENT

Comment: My Appium information :  info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"18","automationName":"Appium"}

Comment: Confirm the appPack & appActivity from app developers. Alternatively find appActivity & appPack as explained [in this SO answer](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/android-app-testing-with-appium/12382#12382).

Comment: I have appPack and entered appActivity too from adb logs. Now I am facing error : (org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.)

Comment: It is looking for Chrome. Is chrome installed on your device?

Comment: Yes, chrome is installed in device. But what is the solution for that error?

Comment: I have changed from RemoteWebDriver to AppiumDriver<>. It is executing and now showing error message : Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: spawn ENOENT

Answer (score 0):

Once you connect your device to System. Please follow the below steps to get you Activity name and package name.

STEPS

1. Open your app in the mobile
2. Open command prompt.
3. Go to Run and type `cmd` for opening the Command Prompt interface.
4. Type `adb devices` in the window. it will list the your android device
5. Type `adb shell`, to get in to the device.
6. Type this comment `dumpsys window windows | grep -E ‘mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp’`
7. Above mentioned command will display the aapPackage and aapActivity

you try to comment the following command.

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

AND you can try the following Sample code;

```
DesiredCapabilities cap1= new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap1.setCapability("deviceName", "devicename");
    cap1.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.4");
    cap1.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap1.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");

    cap1.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.settings");
    cap1.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.settings.Settings");


    AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4888/wd/hub"), cap1);
```

Above sample command will open `settings` in android device

Comment: I have done same steps, getting error : org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Permission to start activity denied.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

try this great post [create appium node + android driver](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-create-appium-android-driver-arie-hoenel) it will help you to setup environment you need for testing